# Bulk Download Background Images

Tags: download, background-image

Is there any way to bulk download background images from an image sequence?
Specifically, I'm looking to download the different image sequences from this website: lookbook.reebok.com

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to it. In terminal, write     curl http://asdf.com/what/ever/image/img[00-99].gif -o img#1.gif     And change it to your desired URL, number of images and format. If you write a number thats higher than what exists, terminal will create empty files in the format you requested.